# System.FormatException and delete not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have created a **gridview**, for the user to **add**/**edit** and **remove** products. (not actually deleting but declaring it discontinued on the database)

I am getting the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   but was not handled in user code

My markup is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="addProduct.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_addProduct" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightCol" runat="Server">
<h1>Products</h1>
<asp:Label ID="lblProdGrd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lstCatSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:bncConn %>'  SelectCommand="SELECT CategoryName, CategoryId FROM ProductDetails.Category"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lstSubCatSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:bncConn %>' SelectCommand="SELECT ProductType, ProductTypeId FROM ProductDetails.ProductType"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lstImgSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:bncConn %>' SelectCommand="SELECT ImageName, ImageId, ImagePath FROM ProductDetails.ProductImages"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView
    ID="grdProds"
    runat="server"
    AllowPaging="true"
    ShowFooter="true"
    PageSize="5"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnPageIndexChanging="grdProds_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdProds_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowCommand="grdProds_RowCommand"
    OnRowEditing="grdProds_RowEditing"
    OnRowUpdating="grdProds_RowUpdating"
    onrowdeleting="grdProds_RowDeleting">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Product ID" FooterText="Product ID" HeaderText="Product ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProdId" Text='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAdd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Product Name" HeaderText="Product Name" FooterText="ProductName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Description" AccessibleHeaderText="Product description" FooterText="Product Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDescription" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Price" AccessibleHeaderText="Product Price" FooterText="Product Price">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price") %>' TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCatEdit" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstCatSrc" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--(Select a category)--" Value="NULL"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstCatSrc" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--(Select a category)--" Value="NULL"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Category" AccessibleHeaderText="Sub-Category" FooterText="Sub-Category">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSubCat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductType") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstSubCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstSubCatSrc" DataTextField="ProductType" DataValueField="ProductTypeId"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstAddSubCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstSubCatSrc" DataTextField="ProductType" DataValueField="ProductTypeId"></asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product Image" AccessibleHeaderText="Product Image" FooterText="Product Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgProd" runat="server" Height="250" Width="250" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstProdImg" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstImgSrc" DataTextField="ImageName" DataValueField="ImageId"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Image ID="imgProdEdit" runat="server" Height="250" Width="250" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="lstAddProdImg" runat="server" DataSourceID="lstImgSrc" DataTextField="ImageName" DataValueField="ImageId"></asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item in stock" AccessibleHeaderText="Item in stock" FooterText="Item in stock">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInStock" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("InStock") %>' Enabled="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInStockEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("InStock") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkInStockAdd" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pre-Designed" AccessibleHeaderText="Pre-designed" FooterText="Pre-Designed">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPrePrinted" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("PrePrinted") %>' Enabled="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPrePrintedEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("PrePrinted") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAddPrePrinted" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                <br />
                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to declare this product Discontinued?')">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddRecord" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Add"></asp:Button>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using BillyNicClothingModel;
public partial class Admin_addProduct : System.Web.UI.Page
{

private string connectionString =
   WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bncConn"].ConnectionString;
string CatLst;



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {

        BindGrid();
    }

}

protected void BindGrid()
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductDetails.bnc_Products", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

    cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Display";

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Products");
        grdProds.DataSource = ds;
        grdProds.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblProdGrd.Text = err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }


}

protected void grdProds_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    grdProds.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    BindGrid();

}
protected void grdProds_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{

    grdProds.EditIndex = -1;

    BindGrid();

}
protected void grdProds_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add"))
    {



        TextBox txtName = (TextBox)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddname");
        TextBox txtDescription = (TextBox)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDescription");
        TextBox txtPrice = (TextBox)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddPrice");
        DropDownList lstCatEdit = (DropDownList)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("lstCat");
        DropDownList lstSubCat = (DropDownList)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("lstAddSubCat");
        DropDownList lstImageProd = (DropDownList)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("lstAddProdImg");
        CheckBox chkInStockEdit = (CheckBox)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("chkInStockAdd");
        CheckBox chkPrePrinted = (CheckBox)grdProds.FooterRow.FindControl("chkAddPrePinted");

        string ProductName, Description;
        int Category, Image;
        bool InStock, Preprinted;
        decimal Price;
        byte SubCat;

        ProductName = txtName.Text;
        Description = txtDescription.Text;
        Price = Decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        Category = int.Parse(lstCatEdit.SelectedValue);
        SubCat = byte.Parse(lstSubCat.SelectedValue);
        Image = int.Parse(lstImageProd.SelectedValue);
        InStock = chkInStockEdit.Checked;
        Preprinted = chkPrePrinted.Checked;

        AddProduct(ProductName, Description, Price, Category, SubCat, Image, InStock, Preprinted);

        grdProds.EditIndex = -1;

        BindGrid();

    }

}
protected void AddProduct(string ProductName, string Description, decimal Price, int Category, int SubCat, 
    int Image, bool InStock, bool Preprinted)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductDetails.bnc_Products", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Add";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value = ProductName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", Description));
    cmd.Parameters["@Description"].Value = Description;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", SqlDbType.Money));
    cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = Price;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = Category;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductType", SqlDbType.TinyInt));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProductType"].Value = SubCat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = Image;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InStock", SqlDbType.Bit));
    cmd.Parameters["@InStock"].Value = InStock;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrePrinted", SqlDbType.Bit));
    cmd.Parameters["@PrePrinted"].Value = Preprinted;


    try {
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblProdGrd.Text = err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void grdProds_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    Label prId = (Label)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblProdId");
    int pId = Convert.ToInt32(prId.Text);
    DeleteProduct(pId);
    grdProds.EditIndex = -1;

    BindGrid();

}
protected void DeleteProduct(int pId)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductDetails.bnc_Products", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Delete";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProdId", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProdId"].Value = pId;

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblProdGrd.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void grdProds_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    grdProds.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    BindGrid();

}
protected void grdProds_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    Label prdId = (Label)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblProdId");
    TextBox Name = (TextBox)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName");
    TextBox Description = (TextBox)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox Price = (TextBox)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPrice");
    DropDownList Category = (DropDownList)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lstCatEdit");
    DropDownList SubCat = (DropDownList)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lstSubCat");
    DropDownList Image = (DropDownList)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lstProdImg");
    CheckBox InStock = (CheckBox)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkInStockEdit");
    CheckBox PrePrinted = (CheckBox)grdProds.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("chkPrePrintedEdit");

    int ProdId = Convert.ToInt32(prdId.Text);
    string eName = Name.Text;
    string eDescription = Description.Text;
    Decimal ePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(Price.Text);
    int eCat = Convert.ToInt32(Category.SelectedValue);
    byte eSCat = Convert.ToByte(SubCat.SelectedValue);
    int eImage = Convert.ToInt32(Image.SelectedValue);
    bool eInstock = InStock.Checked;
    bool ePreprinted = PrePrinted.Checked;


    UpdateProduct(ProdId, eName, eDescription, ePrice, eCat, eSCat, eImage, eInstock, ePreprinted);
    grdProds.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();

}

protected void UpdateProduct(int ProdId, string eName, string eDescription, Decimal ePrice, int eCat, byte eSCat, int eImage, bool eInstock, bool ePreprinted)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ProductDetails.bnc_Products", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProdId", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProdId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ProdId);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@Status"].Value = "Update";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value = eName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1));
    cmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = eDescription;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Price", SqlDbType.Money));
    cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = ePrice;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = eCat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductType", SqlDbType.TinyInt));
    cmd.Parameters["@ProductType"].Value = eSCat;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = eImage;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InStock", SqlDbType.Bit));
    cmd.Parameters["@InStock"].Value = eInstock;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PrePrinted", SqlDbType.Bit));
    cmd.Parameters["@PrePrinted"].Value = ePreprinted;

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblProdGrd.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ProductDetails].[bnc_Products] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ProdId int = 0,
@Category int = 0,
@ProductType tinyint = 0, 
@Price money = 0,
@InStock bit = 1,
@ProductName varchar(50) = '',
@Image int = 0,
@Description varchar(max) = '',
@PrePrinted bit = 1,
@Discontinued bit = 0,
@Status varchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

if (@Status = 'Display')
begin
select p.ProductId,p.ProductName,c.CategoryId,c.CategoryName,
       pt.ProductType,pt.ProductTypeId,p.Price,p.InStock,pi.ImagePath,
  pi.ImageId,pi.ImageName,p.Description,p.PrePrinted,p.Discontinued

 from ProductDetails.Products p
join ProductDetails.Category c on c.CategoryId = p.Category
join ProductDetails.ProductType pt on pt.ProductTypeId = p.ProductType
join ProductDetails.ProductImages pi on pi.ImageId = p.ImageId
where p.Discontinued = 0  
end
else if(@Status = 'Update')
begin
update Productdetails.Products
set Category = @Category, ProductType = @ProductType, 
Price = @Price, InStock = @InStock, ProductName = @ProductName, 
ImageId = @Image, Description = @Description, PrePrinted = @PrePrinted
where ProductId = @ProdId
end
else if(@Status = 'Add')
begin
insert into ProductDetails.Products
(Category,ProductType,Price,InStock,ProductName,ImageId,Description,PrePrinted,Discontinued)
values    (@Category,@ProductType,@Price,@InStock,@ProductName,@Image,@Description,@PrePrinted,@Discontinued)
end
else if(@Status = 'Delete')
begin
Update ProductDetails.Products
set Discontinued = @Discontinued
where ProductId = @ProdId
end
END
```

Also when I try to **delete** a product, well declare it to be discontinued, nothing seems to happen and if anyone is able to point out where and what is wrong I would be very grateful as I am at a total loss as to what's going on. Sorry if any of this seems a little vague, I'm quite the novice at this, and so am at a complete standstill at the moment. Thank you in advanced to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting `System.FormatException` as have opened the following `asp:content` but have not closed it:

```
<asp:content id="Content3" contentplaceholderid="RightCol" runat="Server">
```

So after `</asp:GridView>` put `</asp:content>` and `delete function` will get executed.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but on my markup it is present, it just didn't quite make it over to my post when I copied and pasted. that was the only thing that didn't make the post, everything else is present.

Comment: @M_Griffiths I just created your page on my machine and is working fine(obviously removed columns and connection etc).

Comment: oh how very strange, its not on mine. it displays the page fine and I can go into edit products but when I try to save the edits to db I get the above mentioned exception. and also delete(declaring discontinued) doesn't seem to do anything at the moment but does not give any errors or exceptions. the grid refreshes but product still there

Comment: I see so you get this when running the stored proc. which line exactly throws this exception

Comment: I have now fixed the delete issue, I had missed a parameter in my code behind that the sp required for it to do what it needed.

Comment: i am however still getting the above mentioned exception when i try to save edits. The exception is on the following line: [code]int eCat = Convert.ToInt32(Category.SelectedValue);[/code] of the following event handler [code] protected void grdProds_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)[/code]

Comment: check if category's selectedValue is a number

Comment: as far as I can tell it is a number. it should be the id field from the db, which is an int column

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint and see what is the value when you update

Comment: I have managed to sort the issue out. I have changed default values on numeric parameters in my sp from 0 to null. Thank you so much for your help, I could not have done it without your guidance :) I have marked this post as answer as it through this post that a solution was found